# Checking the visibility of a div not working inside ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Well long story short, I am trying hide a div inside Ajax success function depending on whether its visible or not. But don't understand why it isn't working. I can set it to hide simply and which works but in the console when I check I find that it keeps on setting the div to `display:none` even if it is already hidden.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#loading').show();
            setInterval(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "generate_list.php",
                    success: function (result) {
                        //$('#loading').hide();
                        $('#loading:visible').hide();

                        if(result != '') {
                            $('#empty_storage').hide();
                            $('#file_list').html(result);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#file_list').html('');
                            $('#empty_storage').show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 1700);
        });
```

Comment: Just curious, Do you really need to check `:visible`?

Comment: You can simply `.hide()` an element

Comment: @Satpal, although not required, i can simply use hide. but if you check the console it keeps setting the visibility to hidden every time

Comment: You might want to set things so that on success you use a setTimeout to recall rather than a setInterval calling an ajax request.

Comment: @JonSG, an example would be good enough.

Comment: Ayan, can you show me the div in the HTML code please. The simple .hide() and .show() are enough for it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle visibility

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loading').css('visibility': 'visible');
        setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "generate_list.php",
                success: function (result) {

                   if ($('#loading').css('visibility') == 'visible') {
                       $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden'); 
                    }

                    if(result != '') {
                        $('#empty_storage').hide();
                        $('#file_list').html(result);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#file_list').html('');
                        $('#empty_storage').show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 1700);
    });
```

CSS : Initially loader will be hidden

```
#loading { 
   visibility : hidden;
 }
```

So go with visibility property if you want to check the visibility. But if you want to use **.hide()** or **.show()** then it depends on **display** property

Visibility :  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp

Display : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Sample Demo : https://jsbin.com/jiluren/11/edit?html,css,js,output

Hope this helps. Thanks !

Comment: see my comment above.

Comment: Updated my answer about visibility and also doing hide() or fadeOut() it will change the display property but not the visibility. So if you want to modify visibility then I am going to update my answer wait !

Comment: I used       `if($('#loading').is(":visible")) {
       $('#loading').hide();
      }`

Comment: as you have set the initial property to `visibility:hidden`, you need to change the code a bit so that it shows up on load which wont show using `show()`.

Comment: Yes use $('#loading').css('visibility': 'visible'); instead of show()

Comment: This does makes your anser perfect. Thanks. (By the way looking at your profile I had something to ask you apart from this. May be we could create a chat.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123353/discussion-between-ayan-and-krishcdbry).

Comment: Yes sure in 20 min : will chat in linkedin ? http://in.linkedin.com/in/krishcdbry ??

Comment: Well am not on linkedin at the moment. I have created a chat. May be we can have a talk over there.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that you misplaced the call of showing the loading indicator. You call `$('#loading').show();` only once, before starting the `setInterval` iteration. So the first time your `#loading` gets hidden, it will stay hidden forever. You should call `$('#loading').show();` before each `ajax` call like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#loading').show();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "generate_list.php",
                    success: function (result) {
                        //$('#loading').hide();
                        $('#loading:visible').hide();

                        if(result != '') {
                            $('#empty_storage').hide();
                            $('#file_list').html(result);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#file_list').html('');
                            $('#empty_storage').show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, 1700);
        });
```

Also, note that for such a *loading* indication it's better to hide it in the `always` callback of the promise returned by `$.ajax`. That way the loading panel will be hidden also when an error occures, and the success callback is not called. I mean something like thi.

```
$("#loading").show();
$.ajax({ ... })
 .always(function() {
    $("#loading").hide();    
  });
```

Comment: I need to show the loading icon only once and that is every time the page loads and not on every ajax call.

Comment: I see, then I actually don't understand your problem, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your requirement , you need to show the loading icon before ajax call and hide it once ajax call completes

In that case there are predefined callback functions avialable

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
     $("#loaderforsearch").show()
    },

                    complete: function()
                    {
                       $("#loaderforsearch").hide();
                    },
```